# Array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement

:)

I wanna ask...
I made form Register, like this :

```
Username : --------   
Password : --------
```

I want when I click button "SAVE" username and password will saved in array...

I have Regfragment.java :

```
 public class RegFragment extends Fragment {

EditText text1,text2,text3;
Button btn1;
public static List<String> usr = new ArrayList<String>();  -----> ARRAY
public static List<String> pwd = new ArrayList<String>();  -----> ARRAY

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);
    text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text3 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text3);

    btn1  = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new klik());       

    return rootView;         
}

class klik implements Button.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            usr.add(text1.getText().toString());   -----> will be the item
            pwd.add(text1.getText().toString());   -----> will be the item
        }
        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Form1.class);
        getActivity().finish();
        startActivity(i);
    }
      }
 }
```

Can you check it....?
and after Username and Password saved...
I'll call it on another form...I'll use "IF"....

but how to call array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to get username and password at other Form1 activity? 
then you fill username and password in Intent.

ex)
Regfragment.java

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = Intent(getActivity(),Form1.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", username);
    intent.putExtra("password", password);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Form1.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String username = getIntent().getExtra("username");
    String password = getIntent().getExtra("password");

    // do something...
}
```

If you want to send array type to Form1 activity, you use putStringArrayListExtra method instead putExtra method.

Comment: Sir, can you explain it to me ..

intent.putExtra("username", username);

Comment: Each activity can be exchanged few data types.
then intent is used for exchanging.

see developer site below.  
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any failures in your code on quick reviewing it.

If you want to get data from an Array you use the get(int index) function.
This should work for you:

```
private String getUsername() {
    String username = this.usr.get(0) // gets the first username
    return username;
}

// Same for password
private String getPassword() {
    String pasword = this.pwd.get(0) // gets the first username
    return pasword;
}
```

Just a tipp: If you're handling usernames and passwords have a look at the Android Authenticator Service, here are some links for that:

- http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/
- http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2
- http://www.lukeslog.de/?page_id=1052
- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html